# Julia: How can I define the type of an argument to a function as an Array of Tuples?

Tags: julia

I have a 1-dimensional Array of Tuples which I need to pass to a function defined as

```
function f(a::Array{Tuple{Vararg{String}}, 1}) 
    #do some processing
end
```

Each Tuple can have any number of String elements, but the number of elements will be the same for all the Tuples in the Array. For example, the Array could look like `[("x1","x2"),("y1","y2")]` or `[("x1","x2","x3"),("y1","y2","y3")]` etc. Hence the usage of Vararg{String} for this.

Now, when I run `f([("x1","x2"),("y1","y2")])`, it throws an error

> "MethodError: no method matching f(::Array{Tuple{String,String},1})"

How should I modify the function definition so that this works?

Comment: You could just leave out the type description from the function call.

Comment: @niczky12 I need to ensure that the caller sends Tuples with only String elements for my use case.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You get this `MethodError` because `Tuple{Vararg{T}}` is not a concrete type as the number of elements for `Vararg` are left unspecified and [Julia's type parameters are *invariant*](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/types/index.html#Parametric-Composite-Types-1) rather than *covariant*.

Even though we have `Tuple{Vararg{String, 5}} <: Tuple{Vararg{String}}`, we do not have `Vector{Tuple{Vararg{String, 5}}} <: Vector{Tuple{Vararg{String}}}`

```
julia> Tuple{Vararg{String, 5}} <: Tuple{Vararg{String}}
true

julia> Vector{Tuple{Vararg{String, 5}}} <: Vector{Tuple{Vararg{String}}}
false
```

You should instead use the following signatures to get rid of the error

```
function f(a::Vector{<:Tuple{Vararg{String}}})
# or
function f(a::Vector{T}) where {T <: Tuple{Vararg{String}}
```

as suggested by both @crstnbr and @BogumiłKamiński. These signatures will get rid of the error, however, they do not restrict Tuples to be of the same length. For example, you can call these functions with

```
f([("x1, x2"), ("y1", "y2", "y3"])
```

As you want to ensure the tuples in the array contain the same number of elements, you need to specify this restriction in the type annotation. The documentation for `Vararg` provides the information on how to specify the number of elements.

> `Vararg{T,N}`
>
> The last parameter of a tuple type Tuple can be the special type Vararg,
>     which denotes any number of trailing elements. The type `Vararg{T,N}`
>     corresponds to exactly `N` elements of type `T`. `Vararg{T}` corresponds to zero
>     or more elements of type `T`. `Vararg` tuple types are used to represent the
>     arguments accepted by varargs methods (see the section on Varargs Functions
>     in the manual.)

You can go with

```
function f(a::Vector{Tuple{Vararg{String, N}}}) where N 
    ...
end
```

or using the compact way of `NTuple` instead

```
function f(a::Vector{NTuple{N, String}}) where N

end
```

These signatures will *enforce* the restrictions you wanted in the question.

---

#### Notes

You might be [overly specializing your types](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/style-guide/#Avoid-writing-overly-specific-types-1).

As @Bogumił Kamiński noted in the comments section, it is better to work with `AbstractString` type instead of the concrete `String` type.

```
function f(a::Vector{<:NTuple{N, AbstractString}}) where N
...
end
```

You may consider working with `AbstractVector` instead of `Vector`, as well.

Comment: This is a very good answer, one additional comment is that probably you want to write a signature like `g(a::Vector{T}) where {T<:Tuple{Vararg{AbstractString}}}`. The reason is (as noted in the answer) that you probably over-specialized the signature, and in general when working with strings you should accept `AbstractString` as it is really easy to get a `SubString` instead of `String` in Julia.

Comment: @BogumiłKamiński Thanks for the comment! I am going to edit my answer to also reflect your comment but the OP wants to enforce the number of elements in each tuple, as well.  One can go with `f(a::Vector{T}) where {T<:Tuple{Vararg{AbstractString, N}}} where N`. Is there a better syntax that does not need double `where` clause here?

Comment: Good point (I have forgotten about this restriction) - I think - as you write, that you have to take `N` to the outside `where`, so probably the shortest way to write it would be `g(a::Vector{<:NTuple{N, AbstractString}}) where {N}`.

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the signature to

```
function f(a::Array{<:Tuple{Vararg{String}}, 1})
    #do some processing
end
```

Note the `<:` to indicate that all subtypes of `Tuple{Vararg{String}}` are fine.

However, it might be easier to just leave out the type information. The function will have exactly the same speed.

Comment: This method signature is not precise enough (see the answer by @hckr and the discussion in comments there), as it allows tuples to have varying length (I have also forgotten about this restriction in my first proposal).

Comment: I just wanted to leave the comment for possible future readers what is the difference.